# Svelte inconsistency in binding

Tags: svelte-3

I'm new to Svelte and was working with bindings.

Here's my code:

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1cad59da1c994c37bf1c5be16833315f?version=3.38.2)

**test.svelte**

```svelte
<script>
    let a = 1000000;
    let b = "ABCDeFgH";
</script>

A: <input bind:value={a} />
<br><br>
B: <input bind:value={b} />
<br>
<!-- works only on first run -->
<p>Formatted <strong>a</strong> is {a.toLocaleString("en-US")} </p>

<!-- works on update -->
<p>Formatted <strong>b</strong> is {b.toLowerCase()}</p>
```

The `toLocaleString()` method on `a` works on the first load but does not format the output (with commas) when updating the number using the input box during runtime.

However, the `toLowerCase()` seems to work fine even with updates to `b` during runtime.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially it's a number: `100000`, but the input value is a string (`"100000"`), and strings get different behavior from `toLocaleString`. You could run it through `parseInt` or `parseFloat`, `Number` or whatever to convert it back:

```js
console.log((100000).toLocaleString('en-US'));
console.log(("100000").toLocaleString('en-US'));
console.log((Number("100000")).toLocaleString('en-US'));
```

Or better yet, as [Connor points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67978237/636077), just set the input type to "number":

```html
<input bind:value={a} type="number" />
```

Answer (score 1):

No inconsistency: input values are strings by default. Svelte won't know that you are expecting a number back, so `bind`ing `a` converts it to a string after an update (as [@ray pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67978179/6789816), `toLocaleString` won't produce the same result on a string). You can tell Svelte to expect a number by specifying `type="number"` on your input:

```html
<script>
    let a = 1000000;
</script>

A: <input bind:value={a} type="number" />

<p>Formatted <strong>a</strong> is {a.toLocaleString("en-US")} </p>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/40e8d3c8119d407fb1e6309870dc0077?version=3.38.2)

Comment: Oh nice. I tried setting the input type to number and didn't see any difference. Maybe I typo'd it or it didn't refresh. Just tried it again and yeah, that works.